# Has anyone else encountered a glitch with CSS Grid and odd-number pixel dimmed cells? Trying to fix

Tags: css, grid, render, pixel, artifact

I needed to create a dynamically sizable grid that would scale and keep its proportions.  This is for use with games and puzzles so think 20 x 25 cells and filling the shortest relative dimension of its container.  After having things work beautifully in Firefox in very straight forward way, I thought to test it in Chrome and Edge (not even gonna try IE).  That's when I found these mysterious rendering lines between cells where the background and cell contents are blended.  Those lines have to go and that's my problem.

I have all padding, grid gaps, borders and such set to 0.

Here's what I know:  I anticipated rendering glitches and so my resize handler already tweaks the size of the CSS Grid to round to the nearest whole number of whole number sized (in pixels) cells.  This makes everything look quite clean.  However, when the number of columns is odd (like 21) and the width of the cells turns out odd (like 13px because the total width is 273px) the artifact appears.  The same thing happens independently, vertically.  This seems to be some sort of sub-pixel artifact, but I don't know why it should happen when all sizes are integer pixel count.  If I make the cell count 20 or 22, or resize the grid so the cell dimension is 12 or 14px there is no artifact.  Seems to happen at all odd/odd instances.  Whole integer px sizes for grid and cells alike are confirmed using the console inspector and also screen capture.

Note, this happens whether contained by the body or another DIV element, and unaffected by whether   any parent container has whole pixel, or % sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Before I stick the code here... which "oops" I didn't realize was an expectation, let me say I half-solved the issue.  To see it in action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"-->
    <title>Blocks</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative; /*activate child positioning*/
            height: 100vh;      /*fill screen vertically*/
            background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
        }
        #consoleDiv
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;        /*center*/
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="consoleDiv">
    </div>      
    <script>
        function blocks(tElement, bClr, fClr)
        {
            const GRID_ACROSS = 21;
            const GRID_DOWN = 24;
            const aspect = GRID_ACROSS/GRID_DOWN;
            const consoleDiv = document.querySelector("#" + tElement);
            consoleDiv.style.position = "absolute";
            consoleDiv.style.display = "grid";
            consoleDiv.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + GRID_ACROSS + 
",1fr)";
            consoleDiv.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(" + GRID_DOWN + ",1fr)";
            
            for (let n = 1; n < GRID_DOWN + 1; n += 1)
            {
                for (let m = 1; m < GRID_ACROSS + 1; m += 1)
                {
                    newItem = document.createElement("DIV");
                    newItem.className = "gridCell";
                    newItem.style.backgroundColor = bClr;
                    newItem.style.backgroundColor = fClr;
                    newItem.style.gridArea = n + " / " + m;
                    consoleDiv.appendChild(newItem);
                };
            };
            
            let lastWidth = -1;
            let lastHeight = -1;
            return (
            function()
            {
                const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                const wNow = body.clientWidth;
                const hNow = body.clientHeight;
                if ((wNow != lastWidth) || (hNow != lastHeight))
                {
                    const dispAspect = wNow / hNow;
                    consoleDiv.style.height = "100%";
                    consoleDiv.style.width = "100%";
                    if (dispAspect > aspect)
                    {
                        consoleDiv.style.width = 100 * aspect / dispAspect + 
 "%";
                    }
                    else if (dispAspect < aspect)
                    {//space is too tall
                        consoleDiv.style.height = 100 * dispAspect / aspect + 
"%";
                    };
                    const cellWidthPx = Math.floor(consoleDiv.clientWidth / 
GRID_ACROSS);
                    const cellHeightPx = Math.floor(consoleDiv.clientHeight / 
GRID_DOWN);
                    const hTweak = 0;
                    //const hTweak = (GRID_ACROSS % 2) * (cellWidthPx % 2);
                    consoleDiv.style.width = GRID_ACROSS * cellWidthPx + hTweak 
+ "px";
                    consoleDiv.style.height = GRID_DOWN * cellHeightPx + "px";
                    lastWidth = wNow;
                    lastHeight = hNow;
                };
            });
        };
        
        animateBlocks = blocks("consoleDiv", "green", "pink");
        animate = function(timeStamp)
        {
            animateBlocks(timeStamp);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        };
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try resizing (Chrome) and on every other odd sizing "chunk" you should see vertical line artifacts appear.  You can check with console inspector that the grid is a whole number of cell multiples across and each cell is whole pixels.  If you change the GRID_DOWN to an odd number, you will see horizontal artifacts as well.  Edge behavior is even worse - poor on even multiples of odd number pixel cells, too.  In Firefox I see no issues.

The culprit seems to be the transform: translate centering method.  It chokes a little translating to center an odd number of pixels.  Not unreasonable I suppose, but I would never have chosen their 'solution'.

The fix, for me at least, was to check for both odd cell count and odd cell pixel width.  If both odd then a 1px side border added to the grid-containing DIV fixes the issue.  To see the 'fix' REM/unREM the lines defining hTweak.  I haven't tested this in Edge, but I gave up on Microsoft products a while back.

Comment: Tweak doesn't help in Edge, but for a weird reason apparently.  In Edge, the transform still seems to be causing the issues.  But for some reason, the transform itself seems to take my whole pixel cells - say 17px - and render them as 16.99.  I can verify the code computes 17px correctly, and if I remove the transform, the grid is on the left but without glitch / gaps.  Inspector verfies 17px.  When I add back the transform, the lines appear and inspector reports the 16.99px change...??? Do those guys at Microdaft sit around and think up new ways to be problematic?  Trying other centering next

Comment: Using Flex box centering on the grid element avoids the problem altogether - apparently in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.  Okay - just wanted to point out this weird transform/translate + grid glitch.

Comment: Actually, Flex centering of grid that has whole numbered pixels and cells in Edge does seem to render okay, but for some reason pixels widths like 16px (yes, even) still display in the inspector as 15.99px.  I don't get it.  This causes other artifacts down stream that you can imagine arise when actually fine positioning content in the cells.